# Using Qt+ICC on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, icc

I have a question about the use of the Intel C++ compiler on Windows for compiling Qt projects.

I know that officially ICC is supported only by Qt on UNIX, but if it is possible to use ICC from MSVC, then it is probably possible to compile Qt projects with it indirectly.

I tried to connect the compiler to the Qt environment, however, to complete the configuration of the kit, the environment requires a QMake configuration file, but I don't understand much about it, so I can't solve this problem.

I assume that this is unsolvable since they say there is no ICC support. Nevertheless, I am sure that there is a workaround; for example, it would probably be possible to create and debug a project using standard Qt+MinGW tools, then just create something like a makefile and force the compiler to assemble it all. I understand that the compiler does not build, but I do not know what to do. I read quite a lot of information in various sources, but I didn't understand anything :D A similar problem is not mentioned anywhere (or remains unresolved).

Unfortunately, I can't use MSVC to build the project because it uses specific techniques from Qt.

Is the make utility tied to the compiler, or is it really possible to create one makefile, and then just write the desired compiler (and paths) in it?

Answer (score 0):

Intel C++ compiler is not supported for windows in Qt environment.
You can get the details from this link https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html
As of now, Qt environment is also not supported by Intel oneAPI (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-oneapi-base-toolkit-system-requirements.html).

Answer (score 0):

Qt6.3.0 now supports oneAPI on Linux and can be tricked into compiling it on Windows.
Asking Qt to create a win32-icx in QTBUG-102728
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-102728